# Vue 3 - Apply Dynamic Theme on 3rd party Banner using v-bind in SCSS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, vuejs3

I'm using Vue3 [**v-bind in SCSS**](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css), in order to inject dynamic theme to my app. The issue started when I wanted to apply this theme on 3rd party banner (Cookie Consent), which loads after the app been loaded. But I saw Vue does not build this theme variables as CSS hash, but I rather get the following:

```
// Browser CSS Inspect

#banner {
  background-color: var(--7a7a37b1-theme\[\'brand-1\'\]); //when I over on it says "is not defined"
}
```

```
// App.vue

<template>
// some app code in here
</template>

<script>
// 3rd party script for loading the banner
</script>
 
<style lang="scss">
  // the banner with this CSS id, will be created as soon as the script loaded.

  #banner {
    background-color: v-bind("theme['brand-1']");
  }
</style>
```

In conclusion, I'm not sure how to apply this dynamic theme on the banner using Vue and Vite.